# Prevent Flutter/Dart format reordering variable declarations

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, formatting

Is there a way to prevent the dart formatter from reordering variables alphabetically? I can't find a linting rule for it although there's the similar [directives_ordering](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/directives_ordering.html) for imports.

For example

```
var variableA; //A
var variableC; //C
var variableB; //B
```

gets reordered to

```
var variableA; //A
var variableB; //C
var variableC; //B
```

leaving comments in place.

This is especially problematic when I group constants together with a similar purpose and they get split up/mixed with other different constants making the accompanying comments useless/confusing.

I'm using Flutter 2.5.0 on VSCode 1.60.0 with `include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml` in my analysis_options.yaml file.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

For me it turns out this was due to the dart plugin for VSCode. Specifically the `source.sortMembers` value in the `editor.codeActionsOnSave` of my VSCode configuration file.

Setting this to false stops the variables being reordered.
The same behavior happens if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and run Dart: Sort Members.

Answer (score 0):

Apply it for the entire project

Open your `analysis_options.yaml` file

add this line to it

```
    directives_ordering: false
```

Complete code

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    # avoid_print: true # Uncomment to disable the `avoid_print` rule
    # prefer_single_quotes: true  # Uncomment to enable the `prefer_single_quotes` rule
    directives_ordering: false
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to effect either variable ordering nor import ordering. With this rule both still get reordered.